# Can we see the image of inside of our eye, in front of the eye?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

Yesterday, I was sitting with a really bright computer screen (brighter than usual) right in front of me (about 30 cm) and it was like a cubicle (most of the light was blocked from all 3 sides — front, left and right). Only some light was coming from behind.

I was wearing rimless specs (lens: cylindrical -0.5) with its left temple (thing that is connected to the lens and goes behind your ear) broken, so the specs were not parallel to my eyes (perpendicular distance between left lens and my left eye was more than distance between right lens and right eye).

I saw two green circles vertically on top of each other (upper one was sharper and brighter; also it was green — maybe because of blue ray filters on lens), a little left to my left eye. There was a black spot in the middle of the circle(it was shaped like a molecular orbital formed by two 1s orbitals). I could see floater-like things (smaller than the floaters I usually see) in the circle. I think it was the image of the inside of my eye, because while I was closing my left eye, I could see the shadows of my eyelids and eyelashes covering the circle. In addition, when I was moving my head, the circle was also moving. I think the black spot was the blind spot in the eye.

I think of two things:

1. The light from behind me reflected from the lens and went in my eye and then the reflected light ray coming from the inside of my eye formed an image by the lens.
2. The light in front of me went in my eye (and inside of my eye is now bright), and I saw the image of my bright eye, formed by the lens, in front of me.

I don't know if it is a common phenomenon, please answer if you know the explanation.

Comment: Are you tasking about floaters?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes".  I haven't had your exact experience, but when I am getting an eye exam and the eye doctor uses a bright light and a magnifying lens to look at my retinas, I can see the image of the blood vessels on each retina, either from the internal reflections inside my eye, or reflections off of the magnifying lens.

Comment: Note that the blood vessels are *before* the photo-sensitive cells in vertebrate eyes (octopuses have more sensibly arranged eyes for that matter). So they are *always* in the image you see and removed by neural post-filtering. At least for me it is possible to trick that post-filtering by quickly moving a slit (e.g. the gap between two fingers) directly before the eye while looking at a bright surface – this allows me to see the fine blood vessels as fine dark lines in my field of view. Not sure what you see during the eye exams, but I could imagine that it is a similar effect.